What happens if you lose to Koopa Kid in Rock Paper Scissors?
Sometimes while moving around the map a Koopa Kid will appear and challenge me to Rock Paper Scissors. He says he won't do anything to me if I win, but will do something bad to me if I lose. I've either won or tied each time I've seen him, so he hasn't done anything to me.
What happens if you lose to a Koopa Kid in Rock Paper Scissors?


If you lose at Rock Paper Scissors, Bowser will punish you. I've had two different punishments occur.

Bowser blocks your path with a rock. The rock went away after stoppng at a location/point of interest.
Bowser steals a mushroom.


